# Function pointers implication to Object-oriented programming

Tags: c#, oop, delegates, function-pointers, paradigms

In his talk "The Future of Programming", Robert Martin mentions [the motives for structured, functional and object-oriented paradigms](https://youtu.be/ecIWPzGEbFc?t=3465):

- Structured programming: don't use unrestrained `goto`;
- Functional programming: don't use assignment;
- Object-oriented programming: don't use pointers to functions.

But the motive behind OOP which he mentions is confusing to me. Why does C#, as an object-oriented language, has delegates (which to my understanding are function pointers)?

And if OOP is essentially all about avoiding pointers to functions, whats wrong with them?

Comment: It is all about avoiding to handling naked pointers yourself. Internally? There are only pointers and goto's. It has been that way since before the first assembler language and it will propably be into the age of Quantum Computers. Handling Naked Pointers has so many issues. And hte .NET Design team wanted to avoid all of them, by not letting you handle them. Delegetas are just one of the many things that repalce pointers. Out parameters are another.

Comment: Well. We can do anything. We can use pointers in C#, assignments in Js. Anything. But why would we wan't to do it? Are there any better ways ? Those a few question that we should ask ourselves. OOP is not about avoiding pointers, it is about writing your code in a way that doesn't require any pointers to functions...

Comment: @Fabjan After reading the last sentence of your comment, I had that "aha" moment of fitting everything in it's place. Simply, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that is a misrepresentation of Object-Orientation, probably for dramatic effect only.

Object-Orientation's biggest realizations are:

- Hide data, offer functionality (encapsulation, data hiding)
- Tell, don't ask (messaging)
- Strong cohesion, weak coupling
- etc.

None of those specifically forbid pointers to functions technically. What he *could* mean, is that there should be no "static" functions in OO, so there would be obviously no need for pointers to "static" functions. This sounds far-fetched for me...

Summary: I don't know, but it sounds wrong.